# Mathematical equivalent of setting the CRC initial shift register value to all ones

Tags: matlab, crc, equivalent

I have read that initially setting the CRC remainder shift register to all '1's is mathematically equivalent to complement (binary not) the first *n* bits of the message, where *n* is the shift register length. I found this statement in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks#Preset_to_%E2%88%921
, and also in IEEE 802.11ad spec at section 21.3.7, as presented [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6u2r.png).

However, I have try to verified this in MATLAB with no success. Am I doing something wrong, or this statement is actually false? It seems false to me.

```
x = [0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1];
div = [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1];
n = length(div)-1;

% CRC with bit shift strategy
% Set REM shift register initial state to all '1'
x0 = [x zeros(1,n)];
rem0 = ones(1,n);
for k = 1:length(x0)
    rem0 = bitxor([rem0(2:n) x0(k)], rem0(1)*div(2:n+1));
end
disp(rem0)

% CRC with bit shift strategy
% Complement initial n bits
x0 = [bitxor(x, ones(1,8)) zeros(1,8)]; 
rem0 = zeros(1,n);
for k = 1:length(x0)
    rem0 = bitxor([rem0(2:n) x0(k)], rem0(1)*div(2:n+1));
end
disp(rem0)

% CRC Division strategy
% complement initial n 
x0 = bitxor(x, ones(1,n)); 
rem0 = [x0 zeros(1,n)];
for k = 1:length(x0)
    if rem0(k)==1
        rem0(k:k+n)=bitxor(rem0(k:k+n), div);
    end
end
disp(rem0(end-n+1:end))
```

This has resulted in `0111_0101` for the case of setting the initial state of the shift register to 1 and in `0101_0001` for the other two cases where I complemented the initial *n* bits of the input word.

Comment: Initial state of the shift register needs to be set to all 1's: 1111_1111.

Comment: It's true......

Answer (score 1):

The initial shift register value they're talking about is not your initial `rem0`.

Note that if you're *not* trying to invert anything, e.g.:

```
% CRC with bit shift strategy
x0 = [x zeros(1,n)];
rem0 = zeros(1,n);
for k = 1:length(x0)
    rem0 = bitxor([rem0(2:n) x0(k)], rem0(1)*div(2:n+1));
end
disp(rem0)
```

you are doing 16 iterations of the loop, where the first eight do nothing more than shift `x` into `rem0`. So we can instead just set `rem` to `x`, and then do the last eight iterations:

```
% CRC with fewer bit shifts strategy
rem0 = x;
for k = 1:length(x)
    rem0 = bitxor([rem0(2:n) 0], rem0(1)*div(2:n+1));
end
disp(rem0)
```

That is closer to the usual implementation, and now we have the initial `rem0` they're talking about. It really ends up looking like this:

```
% CRC with fewer bit shifts strategy
rem0 = zeros(1,n);
rem0 = bitxor(rem0, x);
for k = 1:length(x)
    rem0 = bitxor([rem0(2:n) 0], rem0(1)*div(2:n+1));
end
disp(rem0)
```

where the initialization of `rem0` happens once, and the rest is repeated for multiple bytes (`x`'s).

Now you can see that for when you want initialize with ones, that for the first `x`:

```
rem0 = ones(1,n);
rem0 = bitxor(rem0, x);
```

is in fact identical to:

```
rem0 = zeros(1,n);
rem0 = bitxor(rem0, bitxor(x, ones(1,n)));
```